Angular mat dialog full screen toggle
I'm working on an Angular application where I have a dialog that displays some JSON data. I want to add a button to toggle this dialog to full screen. I tried setting a panel class and then removing it when toggled, but I couldn't achieve the desired functionality.
As a workaround, I'm currently closing the existing dialog and opening a new one with full screen dimensions (width, maxWidth, height, maxHeight) when the button is clicked. This workaround works, but I feel it is not the most efficient solution.
Here is what I'm currently doing:
openDialog() {
  this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    data: this.jsonData
  });
}

toggleFullScreen() {
  this.dialogRef.close();
  this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
    width: '100vw',
    height: '100vh',
    maxWidth: '100vw',
    maxHeight: '100vh',
    data: this.jsonData
  });
}


DialogRef has the method updateSize that you can use to resize the dialog.
The example below can be placed directly on the modal component.  The same DialogRef that is created in the parent that opens the modal, can be injected to the modal component itself.  This way you can add a button to the dialog itself so that it can be resized from there.  Feel free to put the toggleSize method on the parent, all that matter is the dialogRef.
For the modal sizes you can either have predefined sizes like in your original post, or use auto to let the dialog size itself.
private readonly dialogRef = inject(MatDialogRef);
private isFullScreen = false;

toggleSize(): void {
  if (!this.isFullScreen) {
    this.dialogRef.updateSize('100vw', '100vh');
    this.isFullScreen = true;
  }
  else {
    this.dialogRef.updateSize('auto', 'auto');
    this.isFullScreen = false;
  }
}

StackBlitz Example

Yes, a simpler way is to use the method updateSize of the dialog Ref.
fullscreen() {
  this.dialogRef.updateSize('100vw', '100vh');
}

Note: There is a max width of 80vw, so it won't look like full screen, I overridden this using CSS. It's not perfect but you can tune the CSS to fix your issue.
.cdk-overlay-pane.mat-mdc-dialog-panel {
  max-width: max-content !important;
}

Stackblitz Demo
